# java.util.InputMismatchException; null (in java.util.Scanner)

Tags: java, arrays, txtextcontrol

I have an assignment where I have to read in a file with information about hurricanes from 1980 to 2006. I can not figure out what the error is. I have a section of code like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Hurricanes2
{
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
{
    //declare and initialize variables


    int arrayLength = 59;
    int [] year = new int[arrayLength];
    String [] month = new String[arrayLength];



    File fileName = new File("hurcdata2.txt");
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(fileName);

    //INPUT  - read data in from the file
    int index = 0;
    while (inFile.hasNext()) {
        year[index] = inFile.nextInt();
        month[index] = inFile.next();
    }
    inFile.close();
```

That is just the first part. But in the section with the while statement, there is an error with the `year[index] = inFile.nextInt()`. I have no idea what the error means and I need help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding index++ as the last line of your while loop.  As it is now, you never increment it, so you're only filling and replacing the first numbers in your array.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't change the error. Thanks for trying to help though.

Answer (score 0):

I personally wouldn't use `Scanner()` but instead `Files.readAllLines()`. It might be easier to implement if there is some sort of delimiting character to split the hurricaine data on.

For instance, let's say your text file is this:

`1996, August, 1998, September, 1997, October, 2001, April...`

You can do the following if these assumptions I've made hold true:

```
Path path = Paths.get("hurcdata2.txt");
String hurricaineData = Files.readAllLines(path);

int yearIndex = 0;
int monthIndex = 0;

// Splits the string on a delimiter defined as: zero or more whitespace, 
// a literal comma, zero or more whitespace
for(String value : hurricaineData.split("\\s*,\\s*"))
{
    String integerRegex = "^[1-9]\d*$";
    if(value.matches(integerRegex))
    {
        year[yearIndex++] = value;   
    }
    else
    {
        month[monthIndex++] = value;
    }
}
```